# How to change buttonstyle in WPF, triggered by a boolean?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a Button which changes his Backgroundimage everytime a boolean (IsFavourite) changes.
I tried it with DataTrigger but he don´t know the property: "Source". Can you help me, I´m not that into xaml-code :-(

```
<Style x:Key="starButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="PART_img" Source="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_off_48.png" Height="28" Width="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_img"
                        Property="Source"
                        Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_48.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFavourite}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_48.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFavourite}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_off_48.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
private void StarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsFavourite = !IsFavourite;
}

private bool isFavourite = false;
public bool IsFavourite
{
    get { return isFavourite; }
    set
    {
        isFavourite = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsFavourite");
    }
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

--
The button-event Click calls a method that changes the IsFavourite:

```
<Button Content="Star" Style="{DynamicResource starButtonStyle}" Click="StarButton_Click" />
```

Comment: I don't know it off the top of my head.  What I do is create a button and set the background directly then from that you know the property name and syntax for the value.

Comment: Can you post the code in `StarButton_Click`? And just to clarify, the part that is not working is the `IsFavorite` value is not changing on button click?

Comment: added code, the part that´s not working is that the PropertyChangedEventHandler is null

Comment: @myName does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Rachel of course! - see below, I have solved it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:
With Rachels XAML and the property: `this.DataContext = Classname;` in the constructor it works :-)

Answer (score 6):

Add your Trigger to your Image Style instead of the ControlTemplate

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="28" Width="28">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_off_48.png" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_48.png" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFavourite}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/FtpUploadClient;component/media/star_48.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: @myName I'm not sure what you mean by "handler"... ? If you put a breakpoint in the getter of `IsFavourite`, does it get called?

Comment: have added my C#-code above and yes the getter will be called.

Comment: @myName Are you trying to change the value of `IsFavourite` from the button? Or just try and change the image displayed on the button based on the value of `IsFavourite`? Right now your handler will never get called because you're not changing the value of `IsFavourite`

Comment: I have added an OnClick-Event to the Button that changes the IsFavourite and also have tried to change the value direct after the constructor of my class, nothing worked. The missing code: `<Button Content="Star" Style="{DynamicResource starButtonStyle}" Click="StarButton_Click" />`

Answer (score 0):

1) Does your datacontext implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and is `PropertyChanged("IsFavourite")` raised on the setter? This will ensure that your view gets notified when that property changes.

2) try putting `"Image.Source"` instead of just `"Source"`

3) Try to use `TargetName="PART_img"` on the setter.

Comment: 2) Button doesn't have an `Image` property either.

Answer (score 0):

`Button` doesn't have a `Source` property.

You're trying to set the `Source` of the `Image`, by adding `TargetName="PART_img"` to the `Setter`.